# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'SumServiceReference.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section

Tags: wcf

I want to call a service from both code behind & ajax. I am able to call it from client script using ajax but getting exception, while calling it from code behind.

Here is my sample code, It's a simple sum operation for demo purpose.

Service Contract:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace Sum_WcfService
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    int AddNums(int Num1, int Num2);
}
}
```

Service implementation:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace Sum_WcfService
{
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode
= AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public int AddNums(int Num1, int Num2)
    {
        return Num1 + Num2;
    }
}
}
```

added a client app in the same solution to consume my service 
and added service reference with name "SumServiceReference"

client application:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Sum_WcfService.SumServiceReference;

namespace Sum_WcfService
{
public partial class AddServiceClient : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GetSum(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ServiceProxy = new Service1Client();
        int Num1,Num2;
        int.TryParse(txtNum1.Value, out Num1);
        int.TryParse(txtNum1.Value, out Num2);
        var Sum = ServiceProxy.AddNums(Num1, Num2);
        txtResult.Value = Sum.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
}
```

and my config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name ="SumServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndPointBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service name="Sum_WcfService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="SumServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Sum_WcfService.IService1"       behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehavior" />
  </service>
</services>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/Sum_Wcf/Service1.svc"
   binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
   contract="Sum_WcfService.SumServiceReference.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
              receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
              bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
              textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
              messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
       maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

and error that i am getting is

```
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract    'SumServiceReference.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This  might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the service element as:

```
<service name="Sum_WcfService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="SumServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Sum_WcfService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

and the client element as:

```
<client>
<endpoint address="http://localhost/Sum_Wcf/Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding"
behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehavior" contract="SumServiceReference.IService1" name="WebHttpBinding_Sum" />
</client>
```